# MediaPlayer throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException when running on the phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, media-player

This code works fine when running in the emulator:

```
menuAudio = ScreenManager.Game.Content.Load<Song>("music\\MenuEntry");

// Kick off the music for the title screen
if (MediaPlayer.State != MediaState.Playing)
{
     MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
     MediaPlayer.Play(menuAudio);
     MediaPlayer.Volume = 1f;
}
```

But when I run it to debug on the phone I get a UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to play the menuAudio song.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing this with a phone when connected to a PC, be sure to use WPConnect, rather than Zune. See [these tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaimer/tips-for-debugging-wp7-media-apps-with-wpconnect) for more information.

Have you confirmed that `menuAudio` is valid when you try and play it?